# Folitaion of $\mathbb R^n$ by compact leaves

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, fiber-bundles

By Borel and Serre 1950 (Impossibilité de fibrer un espace euclidien par des fibres compactes. (French))

It is impossible to have this situation of fiber bundles: $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow B$ with compact fibers $F$, unless $F$ is a point.

So now suppose that $\mathbb R^n$ is foliated by compact leaves $\{L_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Delta}$ then the quotient space $B:=\mathbb R^n/\{L_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Delta}$ is Hausdorff and we have the fiber bundle $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow B$ with compact fibers! is this a contradiction of the assumption that  $\mathbb R^n$ is foliated by compact leaves?

Comment: are all the leaves diffeomorphic?

Comment: There is no reason for the projection to the leaf space to be a fiber bundle; preimage of open neighborhoods of $B$ will give saturated neighborhoods of leaves, which need not be trivial (think of the tautological line bundle on $\Bbb{RP}^2$ foliated by the zero section and the $S^0$-subbundles given by $\|x\| = \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0 $). Regarding the titular question: Shockingly, there exists $C^0$-foliations on $\Bbb R^3$ by circles constructed by Vogt, see [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1989__69__215_0.pdf).

Comment: To add on that, homeomorphic leaves is not sufficient to guarantee that a foliation is a fiber bundle either. Consider the circle foliation on the (open) Moebius strip by the center circle and the double covers of the center circle parallel to the boundary. The projection to the leaf space (which is $[0, \infty)$) is not locally trivial at $0$.

Comment: In the setting of $C^0$-foliations, an answer is given by Gael Meigniez in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352796/foliation-of-mathbb-rn-by-connected-compact-manifolds. Namely, there exists a topological foliation of $R^3$ by circles. (Moreover, the leaf space is non-Hausdorff!) For smooth foliations, the problem appears to be open.